# Confusion in not extending results in convergence in probability to convergence in distribution

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

We know that if $X_n\xrightarrow{p}X$ and $Y_n\xrightarrow{p}Y$, then $X_n+Y_n\xrightarrow{p}X+Y$,

and since $X_n\xrightarrow{p}X\Rightarrow X_n\xrightarrow{d}X$ (and simliarly for $Y_n$),

why does it not follow immediately that

$X_n+Y_n\xrightarrow{d}X+Y$?

Comment: Not sure whether I'm understanding your question correctly. Do you want to know whether $X_n \stackrel{P}{\to} X$, $Y_n \stackrel{P}{\to} Y$ implies $X_n+Y_n \stackrel{d}{\to} X+Y$....?

Comment: I know it does not, in general. But I don't know why it shouldn't follow from the above logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the for the convergence in distribution the random variables are not required to be defined on same probability space (and this make this convergence notion so special) and therefore can be hard to define  $P(|X_n+Y_n|\geq \varepsilon)$.